# Gulp and Bower-files: Get js-files for developing and for production

Tags: gulp, bower

I am having tried to read tutorials and browse other questions, but cannot find a good answer to how I can set up gulp so that I get javascript-files from (already installed) bower-components for development and for production.

First I tried a simple way. For development:

```
gulp.task('vendorScriptsDevelopment', function() {
  return gulp.src(['bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                   'bower_components/**/*.js',
                  '!bower_components/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(filter('*.js'))
    .pipe(concat('vendor-scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev'))
});
```

And similar for production:

```
gulp.task('vendorScriptsProduction', function() {
  return gulp.src(['bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
                   'bower_components/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(filter('*.js'))
    .pipe(concat('vendor-scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('prod'))
});
```

I included jquery specifically first, since other plugins often depend on it.

But then I realize that some bower packages includes a lot of files, also various javascript-files that I do not want (I just want "the one" that typically also has a CDN-option (and are offered in two versions, normal js and minimized)).

One [tutorial](http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-package-manager-bower-and-using-gulp-to-manage-components) I have read uses the [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) plugin for the development part, but then it goes on in the wrong direction and wants to make a minified version itself (as I understand, it is always best to use the packages included minified version, as that is optimized from the developers of the plugin).

How can I set up my two Gulp tasks so that they works as intended? Or am I forced to included all the files manually (like I included jquery manually in my examples)?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since nobody has replied, here is my attempt to answer my own question.

I created a function that generates an array of the filenames that I want. This uses [main-bower-files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) and filters out the .js-files. If this is development, then that's it. If it is production, then I just change the file extension from .js to .min.js (and for safety checks if that [file exists](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path)).

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var fs = require('fs');

var vendorScripts = function (minified) {
    var scripts = mainBowerFiles().filter(function (filename) {
      return filename.match(/.+\.js$/)
    });
    if (minified) {
      scripts = scripts.map(function (orgFilename) {
        var minFilename = orgFilename.replace(/^(.+)\.js$/, '$1.min.js');
        if (fs.existsSync(minFilename)) {
          return minFilename
        }
        return orgFilename;
      });
    }
    return scripts;
};

gulp.task('vendorScriptsDevelopment', function() {
  return gulp.src(vendorScripts())
    .pipe(concat('vendor-scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dev'))
});

gulp.task('vendorScriptsProduction', function() {
  return gulp.src(vendorScripts(true))
    .pipe(concat('vendor-scripts.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

I should change my function to handle other assets too, like css.

If somebody has a better approach, I would be very glad for a suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for your problem enjoy:

Create a **vendors.json** file in your sources folder. Edit the file and make path to relevant files you want to include in the production folder. For example:

```
{
    "js" : [
        "lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "lib/lodash/lodash.js",
        "lib/angular/angular.js",
        "lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
        "lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js",
        "lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js",
        "lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "lib/chartjs/Chart.js",
        "lib/pnotify/pnotify.core.js",
        "lib/pnotify/pnotify.buttons.js",
        "lib/angular-pnotify/src/angular-pnotify.js",
        "lib/angular-prompt/dist/angular-prompt.js",
        "lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"
    ],

    "css" : [
        "lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "lib/bootstrap-rtl/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.css",
        "lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css",
        "lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "lib/pnotify/pnotify.core.css",
        "lib/pnotify/pnotify.buttons.css"
    ],
    "statics" : [
        "lib/font-awesome/fonts/*"
    ]
}
```

Then in the **gulpFile.js** add this:

```
var sources = {
    get 'vendor.js'(){
        return getVendorSources().js;
    },
    get 'vendor.css'(){
        return getVendorSources().css;
    },
    get 'vendor.statics'(){
        return getVendorSources().statics;
    }
};

function getVendorSources(){
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('yourSourcesFolder/vendor.json', 'utf-8'));
}

gulp.task('vendor.css', function() {
    return gulp.src(sources['vendor.css'])
        .pipe(changed(paths.dist))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist));
});
```

and so on for the js and static files tasks.